# openssl HMAC-256 cli versus c difference

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, openssl

Am trying to use Amazon S4 signature to upload files to AWS.
Stuck at the following issue:

I have the following inputs:

```
key: c78f26fe3edfb9237f1a00cfb4f65abeb81eb9e0feb1611c30f8c197b0916021
data: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20200602T160158Z\n20200602/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n2340a01622333dc8c490805aa602e200c7b3313727dfee7dc5d736c60ae73862'
```

openssl-cli :

```
$ printf 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20200602T160158Z\n20200602/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n2340a01622333dc8c490805aa602e200c7b3313727dfee7dc5d736c60ae73862' | /usr/bin/openssl dgst -binary -hex -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:c78f26fe3edfb9237f1a00cfb4f65abeb81eb9e0feb1611c30f8c197b0916021
(stdin)= 5c4fda4d67a1afb2599bbc3482ff45088cbe93a302388f0afa626534466ec00a
```

Am using following for signature calculation in c:

```
        char outputBuffer[65] = {0};
        uint8_t* sig = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen(key), (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data), NULL, NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
            sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", sig[i]);
        }
        outputBuffer[64] = 0;

        outputBuffer: 2d56227fdc966653c20f8befa5d36ac68bec41e0d4c2edf56115ddb3e73b442e
```

As per Amazon docs, we need to do the following to create signature

```
DateKey              = HMAC-SHA256("AWS4"+"<SecretAccessKey>", "<YYYYMMDD>")
DateRegionKey        = HMAC-SHA256(<DateKey>, "<aws-region>")
DateRegionServiceKey = HMAC-SHA256(<DateRegionKey>, "<aws-service>")
SigningKey           = HMAC-SHA256(<DateRegionServiceKey>, "aws4_request")
Signature            = HMAC-SHA256(SigningKey, StringToSign)
```

For DateKey, DateRegionKey, DateRegionServiceKey, SigningKey output of both openssl-cli as well as C-function are same.

Only for Signature calculation, am seeing the difference.

Amazon uses the HASH generated from openssl-cli.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Trinadh

Comment: I'll near-guarantee you that "key" is actually supposed to be xlated to raw octets *first*, (32 of them to be precise).

Comment: key is given as 32 octets only. Before passing the key to the function, i generated hex-key to compare with openssl-cli. Except for the signature which is the last part, rest of all outputs are same for both C and openssl-cli

Comment: If that were trie the code is still wrong. You do not use strlen on a byte array. Especially that one (note the zero octet).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig for pointing it out. I tried properly sending the length parameter instead of strlen(). Now it works fine. Thanks